# Fastest way to split a pandas dataframe into a list of subdataframes

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe `df` for which I have a full list `indices` of unique elements in `df.index`. I now want to create a list of all the subdataframes indexed by elements in `indices`; specifically

```
list_df = [df.loc[x] for x in indices]
```

Running this command is taking ages though (`df` has about `3e6` rows, and `3e3` unique indices). Is this a reasonable way to perform this operation? I would be very happy to receive any kind of comments or suggestions that could improve the performance of this and related problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would be glad if the downvoter could let me know how to improve my question. Thanks!

Comment: you might wanna look at `np.array_split`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use list comprehension in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object by index - `level=0`, `sort=False` change default sorting for faster solution:

```
L = [x for i, x in df.groupby(level=0, sort=False)]
```

---

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000
L = list('abcdefghijklmno')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'B':np.random.randint(10, size=N)}, index=np.random.randint(100, size=N))

In [273]: %timeit [x for i, x in df.groupby(level=0, sort=False)]
100 loops, best of 3: 9.91 ms per loop

In [274]: %timeit [df.loc[x] for x in df.index]
1 loop, best of 3: 417 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply! I'm going to try out if this solution is faster.

Comment: Thanks, it is massively faster! Could you explain why this happens?

Comment: On my personal example: `197.030567884 seconds` for my solution, and `1.07291507721 seconds` for jezrael's solution, which goes down to `0.949830770493 seconds` if `sort=False`.

Comment: Just came across this solution and I love it! Thanks @jezrael!